# Convert HTML to PDF - Instantiated Object not visible

Tags: java, html, maven, pdf, converters

I'm currently trying to develop a converter in Java which converts a HTML file to a PDF file and found [this site](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071749/java-app-dev/convert-html-content-to-pdf-format.html). On the bottom of first page and the second page there are code examples on how to realize such a program with the libraries named on page 1 (JTidy, Xalan, FOP).

I created a new Maven project in Spring Tool Suite and added the library dependencies to my pom.xml. I've copied the code parts into this newly created test program to see if it works. Everything was fine up to the last code part.

```
public static byte[] fo2PDF(Document foDocument) {
    DocumentInputSource fopInputSource = new DocumentInputSource(
                                                     foDocument);
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Logger log = new ConsoleLogger(ConsoleLogger.LEVEL_WARN);
        Driver driver = new Driver(fopInputSource, out);
        driver.setLogger(log);
        driver.setRenderer(Driver.RENDER_PDF);
        driver.run();
        return out.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

At first Spring shown this message when going with the cursor over `DocumentInputSource`

> DocumentInputSource cannot be resolved to a type

and there were no option to add a specific library as Maven offers normally.

I tried different things, for example putting the code in a different scope inside of the class, creating an own class for it and I've tried using another IDE, though I doubt that the fault would be solved by any of these things and well, it didn't help obviously.

I've read that the FOP library is licensed under Apache license version 2.0 and added the license at the bottom of my project, just to make sure that it's not causing any trouble, though I didn't expect any success again.

Furthermore I've tried to add another library about which I read that it is necessary for the converted but it wasn't mentionend in the article I linked in the beginning. The library is dom4j.

Now, when I go over `DocumentInputSource`  Spring shows me that:

> The type DocumentInputSource is not visible

This makes no sense to me as it's just a "normal method" inside of my class and as you can see I've already changed the modifier from private to public in order to make sure that it is visible.

I feel like I'm overlooking something very easy/basic and I'd be very grateful for any help. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

PS: This is my very first post here on Stack Overflow and I'm somewhat new to programming. If there's any missing information; please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you mentioned, the `DocumentInputSource` class is from package `org.apache.fop.tools`.

There is another class by this name in package `org.dom4j.io`, which is package-private. If you imported this one, the compiler will warn you that this class is not visible (unless of course your class was in the same package).

Ensure you have the following line near the beginning of your source file :

`import org.apache.fop.tools.DocumentInputSource;`

and not this one :

`import org.dom4j.io.DocumentInputSource;`

Then, if it says the it doesn't find class `org.apache.fop.tools.DocumentInputSource` (or its package), then you are missing the fop dependency in your pom :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>fop</groupId>
   <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
   <version>0.20.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The page you found, and the version of fop it refers to (0.20.5) is rather old (May 2006, see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fop/fop/0.20.5)), and the class you are looking for is not present any more in recent versions of the library. Did you use a recent version in your Maven dependency ? This would explain your first problem ("cannot be resolved to a type").

I suggest you upgrade to the latest stable version (2.1 is dated Jan. 2016, see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/fop/2.1)) and study the examples from their official documentation [here](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) (in the menu on the left you have an "examples" section).

Good luck ! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The fault was indeed that I used a wrong version (2.1) instead of the 0.20.5 version and I didn't check whether the mentionend methods/classes are still inside the library. Now with version 0.20.5 it works! Though I will have a look into the (2.1) version and try to adapt the code to it, once again: thank you very much! :)